# Fixed IP pool when working with autoscale google container engine

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I work with some third party APIs and they require me to send them IP in order for them to whitelist first before we can use it.

Now I'm migrating my apps over to Google Container Engine and the IP get assigned automatically.

Is there anyway for me to setup an IP pool and new node inside the cluster will pick up IP from that pool only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a feature built into the cloud platform (that I know of) that will do this for external IP addresses (you can use [subnets](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/subnetworks) to do this for internal IP addresses).

One option is to set up an outgoing proxy with a [reserved external IP](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/configure-instance-ip-addresses#assign_new_instance) and send all traffic destined for the third party API through the proxy. Then you can control the source IP address of the connections while still taking advantage of the elasticity of Google Container Engine.